# Initial wordpress deploy via git

Tags: git, deployment

Currently, I've got my local machine setup and pushing to staging via git.

There are cases where I upload images locally to test admin page interaction.

In my `.gitignore` file I'm ignoring everything but the theme and plugin folders. I'm curious as to how you handle the initial push to a staging server.  Namely the uploads folder. Do you push everything, then modify the `.gitignore` file to not show uploads?

Just trying to perfect my process. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I treat git like my closet, I just shove everything into it.

Comment: After some additional research, I found that capistrano combined with wordpress is the way to go. For those interested, more info here:

https://marketpress.com/2013/deploying-wordpress-with-git-and-capistrano/

http://www.mixd.co.uk/blog/deploying-wordpress-using-git-and-capistrano/

Answer (score 0):

I set up every environment with a fresh Wordpress installation. Then I do an initial commit from my local dev and start working there with [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/en/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow). Then I deploy the develop branch to the staging environment and the master branch to the live site. I ignore all the uploads in `wp-content/uploads`. Every instance will be packed with different contents, since every environment will mainly be accessed by someone different / for a different purpose / at a different project time. Here's my `.gitignore`:

```
# http://www.stumiller.me/what-should-be-excluded-in-a-wordpress-gitignore-file/
*~
.DS_Store
.svn
.cvs
*.bak
*.swp
Thumbs.db
wp-config.php
wp-content/uploads/
wp-content/blogs.dir/
wp-content/upgrade/
wp-content/backup-db/
wp-content/advanced-cache.php
wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
wp-content/cache/*
wp-content/cache/supercache/*
*.log
wp-content/cache/
wp-content/backups/
sitemap.xml
sitemap.xml.gz

# http://roybarber.com/version-controlling-wordpress/
wp-content/themes/*/.sass-cache/*
wp-config-local.php
readme.html
license.txt
```